# modx : changing label text language in MIGX

Tags: php, modx-revolution, lexicon

I am new to modx. I am using MIGX to create some CMP. I gave the menu tab name as `migx.hello` and in core->compontents->migx->lexicon->en->default.inc.php I added a label

```
$_lang['migx.hello'] = 'Hello World';
```

But the when I load the page page, its showing migx.hello and not showing the value.  Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Always clear cache after after changes in lexicon.
2. Never change the lexicon in files, use "Lexicon Management" instead.